# Would it be possible to exclude relocation reimbursement from income if I incurred it in 2017 but received in Feb-2018?

Tags: united-states, taxes, moving, relocation

I have recently filed 2017 taxes and received my refund. There, I'd some qualified excludable moving expenses under W-2 column 12d (code P). However, I had not submitted all of relocation expenses that I incurred during year 2017 due to the fact that most of receipt were for Dec-2017.

Towards the same, I will be getting additional reimbursement sometime next month. Given the new tax law eliminates "excludable moving expense", I will be now taxed for that remaining relocation reimbursement and it will be not be considered excludable.

I would like to know if I can amend 2017 tax form or request in 2018 taxes to consider remaining reimbursement I receive this month as tax-excludable given it was for year 2017 or there is no way to exclude it as I was paid in year 2018? Deduction is of little value as I take standard deduction!

Comment: See cross-posting and reply at https://ttlc.intuit.com/replies/6607586

Comment: The moving expense deduction was above-the-line and thus available even if you don't itemize -- but for 2018-25 it is 'suspended' by JCTA along with the exclusion for reimbursement, plus you aren't incurring the expenses in 2018 anyway.

Comment: agree with respect to moving expenses made in 2018 and filing 2018 return. However, JCTA is in effect since Jan-1, 2018, effectively allowing deduction for eligible moving expenses (IRS p521) incurred during year 2017 (even with pending reimbursement from an employer) when filing 2017 return.